# Does isomorphisms of sheaf of holomorphic sections implies isomorphisms of two holomorphic vector bundles over the same complex space ?

Tags: complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

My knowledge is very limited for complex geometry. I have the following question:

If we have two complex vector bundles $E\to X$ and $F\to X$ such that we have an isomorphism $\mathcal O\left(E\right) \cong \mathcal O\left(F\right)$ between the sheaf of holomorphic sections, do we have an isomorphism $E \cong F$ ?

Comment: If the bundles are algebraic, then the answer is yes. See Hartshorne, chapter 2, exercise 5.18

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. On  $\mathbb P^1=\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ we have $\Gamma(\mathbb P^1,\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(-1))=\Gamma(\mathbb P^1,\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(-2)=0$, but $O_{\mathbb P^1}(-1)$ and $O_{\mathbb P^1}(-2)$ are not isomorphic.

However on an *affine algebraic* variety $X$, the answer is "yes". There is an amazing equivalence of categories between $\mathcal O(X)$-modules and the so-called quasi coherent sheaves on $X$. It is denoted  $M\mapsto \tilde M.$
 In particular if you have a vector bundle $E$ on $X$, you can recover it (or rather its locally free associated sheaf)  from $M=\Gamma(X,E)$ by this equivalence.
And this remarkable result is not even very difficult! ( Hartshorne, *Algebraic Geometry*, II Corollary 5.5) . And it is valid on any affine *scheme*!

**Another interpretation**
I have interpreted $\mathcal O(E)$ as the vector space $ \Gamma(X,E)$ of global sections of the bundle $E$.
However Donu Arapura and Qfwfq consider that the notation designates the sheaf of sections of the vector bundle $E$, that is the sheaf $\mathcal E$ associating to the open subset $U\subset X$ the vector space $\mathcal E(U)=\Gamma(U,E)$.

In that case the answer is : yes, that sheaf  determines the bundle.
Indeed there is a *canonical* way to obtain  from the sheaf $\mathcal E=\mathcal O(E)$ a holomorphic vector bundle $ Vec(\mathcal E) $ isomorphic to $E$.
Its fiber at $x\in X$ is the the $\mathcal O_{X,x}/ \mathfrak m_x=\mathbb C$- vector space  $Vec(\mathcal E) [x]=\mathcal E _x/\mathfrak m_x \mathcal E_x$.
And the complex structure on $Vec(\mathcal E)=\bigsqcup Vec(\mathcal E) [x]$, is obtained from bijections  with $U\times \mathbb C^r$ for all $U$'s on  which $\mathcal E|U$ is free, that is isomorphic to $\mathcal O^r_U$.
Of course, there are verifications to be made, which are as straightforward as they are boring and unpleasant  to write down explicitly...
**Edit** This latter interpretation is the one chritian had in mind, as he just stated in a comment.

Comment: Dear Georges, I think he meant an isomorphism of sheaves rather
than of just global sections.

Comment: At least I thought so... but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I also interpreted the question as per Donu's comment. Sometimes the notation $\mathcal{O}(E)$ is used to 
indicate the "sheaf of germs of holomorphic sections" of the (geometric) vector bundle $E\to X$. @christian: in 
this case the answer would be "yes", as holomorphic vector bundles are the same as locally free (coherent) analytic sheaves.

Comment:  Dear Donu, dear Qfwfq (by the way, how exactly should one pronounce your name?), what you say is perfectly reasonable and the notation you mention is indeed quite common. Actually, I now consider that  it is so plausible that I have written an edit to take it into account,  so that my answer now addresses both possibilities. Feel free, of course, to post your point of view on these matters: I will certainly read it with interest and pleasure!

Comment: @Georges: it's just a nickname: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmicomics       ;-)

Comment: Dear @Qfwfq, I knew it was a nickname and I was gently teasing you. However the joke is on me, since I didn't know that the nickname was borrowed from that great writer, whose Lezioni americane I read a long time ago. I am very thankful to you for reminding me of him: I'll try to read his novels in Italian in order to improve my knowledge of that (your?) magnificent language

Comment: Yes: I mean isomorphism of sheaves.

the notation $\mathcal O(E)$ designates the sheaf of sections of the vector bundle $E$, that is the sheaf associating to the open subset $U\subset X$ the vector space $E(U)=\Gamma(U,E)$. 

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, dear @christian. I will leave the answer to the other interpretation  in case someone were interested.

Comment: @Donu, @Qfwfq. So you were right all along: bravo!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is true as soon as you assume that the isomorphism of sheaves $\mathcal O(E)\cong\mathcal O(F)$ is $\mathcal O_X$-linear.

To prove, pick a cover $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ of $X$ be opens which are trivializing both for $E$ and $F$. Now if you have an isomorphism of sheaves $\phi:\mathcal O(E)\to\mathcal O(F)$ then you can restrict it to each of these opens and get holomorphic functions $\phi_i:U_i\to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$. If you write carefully the gluing property you'll get something like: on intersections, $f_{ij}\phi_i=\phi_je_ {ij}$, where $e_{ij}$ and $f_{ij}$ are transition functions for $E$ and $F$.

This defines a bundle map.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of looking at the problem is to consider the (set-valued) sheaf of isomorphisms $E\to F$ and the sheaf of isomorphisms $\mathcal O(E)\to\mathcal O(F)$. There is clearly a map from the former to the latter, so we only need to show that it is an isomorphism locally, i.e., we may assume that both $E$ and $F$ are trivial. But then, isomorphisms $E\cong F$ as well as isomorphisms $\mathcal O(E)\cong\mathcal O(F)$ both have an explicit description by elements of $GL_n(\Gamma(U,\mathcal O))$, and it is easily checked that they correspond.